# Slicing in Theano converts a matrix into a vector

Tags: python, slice, theano

Consider the following code snippet:

```
import theano.tensor as T
import theano.tensor
import numpy as np

batch_shape = (50, 40, 30, 30)
batch_size = batch_shape[0]
ncols = batch_shape[1]*batch_shape[2]*batch_shape[3]
minibatch = theano.tensor.tensor4(name='minibatch', 
                                  dtype=theano.config.floatX)
xflat = minibatch.reshape((batch_size,ncols))

partition = np.array([1, 2, 3])
xsub1 = xflat[:,partition]

partition = np.array([1])
xsub2 = xflat[:,partition]

print "xsub1.type: ", xsub1.type
print "xsub2.type: ", xsub2.type
```

If you run it, you get the following output:

```
xsub1.type: TensorType(float64, matrix)
xsub2.type: TensorType(float64, col)
```

Apparently indexing with an array of length 1 turns xsub2 into a col instead of a matrix. How can i make xsub2 be a matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `col` or "column vector" is the name Theano uses for a symbolic matrix that it knows contains only one column. It should be possible to use it just like a matrix.

Theano often doesn't know the shape of a particular symbolic tensor, only its dimensionality. However, in some circumstances, such as that given in the question, Theano is able to infer that a tensor has a particular special case of shape and can sometimes use this information to optimize the computation. This is why `col` (and `row`) exist as special cases of `matrix`.

If you think about the shape more than the type then you'll see that Theano is behaving just the same as numpy:

```
import theano
import theano.tensor
import numpy as np


def compute(minibatch):
    xflat = minibatch.reshape((minibatch.shape[0], -1))
    partition = np.array([1, 2, 3])
    xsub1 = xflat[:, partition]
    partition = np.array([1])
    xsub2 = xflat[:, partition]
    return xsub1, xsub2


def compile_theano_version():
    minibatch = theano.tensor.tensor4(name='minibatch', dtype=theano.config.floatX)
    xsub1, xsub2 = compute(minibatch)
    print xsub1.type, xsub2.type
    return theano.function([minibatch], [xsub1, xsub2])


def numpy_version(minibatch):
    return compute(minibatch)


def main():
    batch_shape = (50, 40, 30, 30)
    minibatch = np.random.standard_normal(size=batch_shape).astype(theano.config.floatX)

    xsub1, xsub2 = numpy_version(minibatch)
    print xsub1.shape, xsub2.shape

    theano_version = compile_theano_version()
    xsub1, xsub2 = theano_version(minibatch)
    print xsub1.shape, xsub2.shape


main()
```

This prints

```
(50L, 3L) (50L, 1L)
TensorType(float64, matrix) TensorType(float64, col)
(50L, 3L) (50L, 1L)
```

So a `col` is indeed a matrix with one column and *not* a vector.

Comment: How would you convert from a col to a matrix? I'm getting an error due to error checks inside Theano that check if the same type of variable is used multiple places and do not allow a (N, 1) col type to be exchanged with a (N, 1) matrix.

Comment: Sorry @pir, I'm no longer working with Theano and don't know the answer to your question. Maybe you could ask a new question on StackOverflow?